# My rails server cannot run on Cloud9

Tags: ruby-on-rails

No matter what I try to do it won't work. Here is my current console code.
All I know is that it has something to do with sass-rails.
I really am looking out for some help here. I understand the GEM cannot be found however, how do I make it so it can be loaded.

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'sass-rails'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/rails:9:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/client.rb:28:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/spring:13:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:3:in `load'
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>



And my GEM file

source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record 
 gem 'sqlite3', group: [:development, :test] 

# Use postgresql as the database for production 
group :production do
   gem 'pg'
   gem 'rails_12factor'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Comment: Did you try running `bundle install`?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the gem and run it without ?

Comment: `bundle show sass-rails` what it gives

Answer (score 0):

try to install nodejs first.

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

The run

```
bundle install
```